# how to get list of port which are in use on the server

Tags: networking, port, windows-server-2003

How to get list of ports which are in use on the server?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Open up a command prompt then type...

```
netstat -a
```

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of options and tools. If you just want a list of listening ports and their owner processes try.

```
netstat -bano
```

Comment: Note that the "b"-option may require admin-rights. (Error: "The requested operation requires elevation.")

Answer (score 6):

> TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and remote addresses and state of TCP connections. On Windows Server 2008, Vista, NT, 2000 and XP TCPView also reports the name of the process that owns the endpoint. TCPView provides a more informative and conveniently presented subset of the Netstat program that ships with Windows. The TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the same functionality.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you mean what ports are listening, you can open a command prompt and write:

```
netstat
```

You can write:

```
netstat /?
```

for an explanation of all options.

Answer (score 1):

[nmap](http://nmap.org/) is a useful tool for this kind of thing