# error in start MySql service in install Xammp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have installed Apache and start Apache service in port 80. But after starting Apache service, MySql service not start and give me this error:

```
11:53:47 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
11:53:47 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:53:53 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

So I have copy the error in log file:

```
2014-10-06 19:42:58 6820 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or      directory
2014-10-06 19:42:58 6820 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

2014-10-06 19:42:58 6820 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-10-06 19:49:17 3392 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2014-10-06 19:49:17 3392 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2014-10-06 19:49:17 3392 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-10-06 19:55:59 6260 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create D:\xampp1\mysql\data\ib_logfile1
2014-10-06 19:55:59 6260 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-10-06 19:55:59 6260 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-10-06 19:55:59 6260 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-10-06 19:55:59 6260 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp1\mysql\data\ibdata1
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-10-06 19:57:45 7920 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp1\mysql\data\ibdata1
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-10-06 19:57:58 6240 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp1\mysql\data\ibdata1
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-10-06 21:10:22 5612 [ERROR] Aborting
```

.......
......

Please help me out to install this web server.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

stop your other mysql service

or

open `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` then change the port

```
...
[mysqld]
port= 3306    <----- change to another port number
...
```

Comment: i have SQLserver in my pc.i dont have MySQL service.

Answer (score 0):

That is because that specific port is currently being used by another service.

http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

https://sites.google.com/site/anashkb/port-80-in-use

A similar question was also asked, you can view it

[Apache server Installation failed(Port 80 or 443 already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418182/apache-server-installation-failedport-80-or-443-already-in-use)

Comment: when i type localhost in my browser,display xammp.but when i click phpmyadmin say error:MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache is uses port 80 and that port is already in use in your system (may be you are using skype).
In order to start the Apache please make free the port 80 in system. (sign out from skype or other program which using port 80). And try again.

Comment: error is in Apache configuration?i think error is in MySQL configuration because apache service have started.